# How to sequentially copy multiple rows (e.g. 1-10 then 11-20 and so on) from one big file using FOR loop to other multiple files (maybe sed or awk)?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm new to Bash and Linux. I'm trying to make it happen in Bash. So far my code looks smth like this:

The problem is with coping using awk or sed, i suppose... as i try to put the sum of a constant and a variable somehow wrong. Brackets or different quotes do not make any difference.

```
for i in {0..10}
do
    touch /path/file$i
    awk -v "NR>=1+$i*9 && NR<=$i*9" /path/BigFile > /path/file$i
    (or with sed) sed -n "1+$i*9,$i*9" /path/BigFile > /path/file$i
done
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try: `split -l 10 BigFile`.

Comment: As  _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers:_ 1. Use single quotes (`'`) around awk programs, not double quotes (`"`). 2. To introduce and use vars in awk: `awk -v var=$i 'NR>=1*var*9...'` 3. No positive value of `i` would satisfy: `NR>=1+i*9 && NR<=i*9`. 4. For a file of 110 records it would be read 11 times. 5. Using just awk you could: `awk 'NR%10==1{close(f);f="file_" ++c}{print > f}' file` (**THIS PRODUCES FILES NAMED `file_n` WHERE `n` IS A NUMBER DEPENDING ON THE SIZE OF `file`**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hobbs' answer (use `split`) is the right way to solve this. Aside from being simpler, it's also linear (meaning that if you double the input size, it only takes twice as long) while these `for` loops are [quadratic](https://twitter.com/BruceDawson0xB/status/1120381406700429312) (doubling the input *quadruples* the time it takes), plus the loop requires that you know in advance how many lines there are in the file. But for completeness let me explain what went wrong in the original attempts.

The primary problem is that the math is wrong. `NR>=1+$i*9 && NR<=$i*9` will *never* be true. For example, in the first iteration, `$i` is 0, so this is equivalent to `NR>=1 && NR<=0`, which requires that the record number be at least 1 but no more than 0. Similarly, when `$i` is 1, it becomes `NR>=10 && NR<=9`... same basic problem. What you want is something like `NR>=1+$i*9 && NR<=($i+1)*9`, which matches for lines 1-9, then 10-18, etc.

The second problem is that you're using awk's `-v` option without supplying a variable name & value. Either remove the `-v`, or (the cleaner option) use `-v` to convert the shell variable `i` into an awk variable (and then put the awk program in single-quotes and don't use `$` to get the variable's value -- that's how you get shell variables' values, not awk variables). Something like this:

```
awk -v i="$i" 'NR>=1+i*9 && NR<=(i+1)*9' /path/BigFile > "/path/file$i"
```

(Note that I double-quoted everything involving a shell variable reference -- not strictly necessary here, but a general good scripting habit.)

The sed version also has a couple of problems of its own. First, unlike awk, sed doesn't do math; if you want to use an expression as a line number, you need to have the shell do the math with `$(( ))` and pass the result to sed as a simple number. Second, your sed command specifies a line range, but doesn't say what to do with it; you need to add a `p` command to print those lines. Something like this:

```
sed -n "$((1+i*9)),$(((i+1)*9)) p" /path/BigFile > "/path/file$i"
```

Or, equivalently, omit `-n` and tell it to delete all but those lines:

```
sed "$((1+i*9)),$(((i+1)*9)) ! d" /path/BigFile > "/path/file$i"
```

But again, don't actually do any of these; use `split` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reinventing this wheel, you can use the `split` utility. `split -l 10` will tell it to split into chunks of 10 lines (or maybe less for the last one), and there are some options you can use to control the output filenames -- you probably want `-d` to get numeric suffixes (the default is alphabetical).